# What, apart from border, margin, and padding, is creating space between my QWidgets?

Tags: qt

I have a QWidget with a QHBoxLayout which contains a QWidget, a QTextArea, and a QWidget.

I have styled them to illustrate the problem. Please view the image in full resolution.

[image]

The parent QWidget has this stylesheet

```
border: 10px dashed blue;
margin:0;
padding:0
```

I expected there to be nothing except blue dashes separating these panels, but you can see grey space in between the borders. Where is it coming from?

It gets worse if I set the style to `border:0`

[image]

With all of border, margin, and padding set to zero there should be *nothing* between the panels, but the amount of grey gutter has increased since the blue dashes were removed.

According to the Qt's documented box model, everything is accounted for.

[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: the spacing of the layout, try setSpacing(0)

Comment: That removes the internal gaps, thanks, but the outer border remains. This is a top-level widget.

Comment: The layout have also a margin. Try setMargin(0)

Comment: That's it, thanks. Want to make that a full answer so I can accept it?