# How to remove unwanted platform-dependent padding in a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, padding

Depending on the platform (KDE Plasma or Ubuntu 16.04), the padding in widgets differ. This is demonstrated in this picture:

[image: Demo on Kubuntu 16.04 (left) and Ubuntu 16.04 (right)]

The printed value is the output of `qlabel->geometry()`. Inspection using Gammaray shows that `sizeHint()` is 77x18 for KDE, but the actual size is 77x33. Apparently there is some platform-specific styling going on, but how can this be disabled in a correct way? (Invoking `setWidth()` or something like that is out of the question as that does not correctly handle all contents.)

The `layoutSpacing()` method does not exist for this widget and invoking `setMargins(0)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35762487/427545) has no effect. I guess that one of the [QStyle PixelMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#PixelMetric-enum) values can be subtracted, but which one exactly? (Is there any documentation on this?)

This is the minimum working example I could think of. The original problem has a QTreeView where too much space exists between cells, but I guess that a solution is transitive.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello, world!");
    QTimer::singleShot(100, [=]() {
        qDebug() << label->geometry();
    });
    label->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `padding: 0px` with a stylesheet?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes, it makes no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Get a widget you can paint yourself with a solid fill (even QLabel + setAutoFillBackground + change its base palette). Does it indeed paint on the entirety of the window's surface, or is there a WM-specific padding?

Comment: @peppe With `label->setStyleSheet("*{background:pink}")` on KDE Plasma, a large area is covered (except for a few pixels on the right and bottom sides). The top padding here is a bit excessive. I was hoping there was some guide on all related components for styling (padding/margins/etc), but the QStyle documentation is not too helpful in this regard.

Comment: Well, the question is whether it's under Qt control or it's the window framing.